# Is it good practice to have @Id annotation under attributes like username or user email

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

What are the complications that might happen when you set `@Id` attributes for a filed other than id, for instance

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="user_id")
private Integer user_id;

@Id
@Size(min=6,message="email is too short")
@Pattern(regexp = "^.+@.+\\..+$",message="invalid email")
@Column(name="user_email")
private String user_email;
```

In my user pojo class: if I'm not defining id annotation for `user_id` but instead for `user_email` will that create any complications in long run?

Comment: `@Id` is the primary key of your entity. Now what could the implications be. Also `@GeneratedValue` only works for `@Id` fields so your current setup won't work.

Answer (score 0):

It is bad practice.

Emails may change, but primary keys (which is what `@Id` annotates) should never change. Usernames may change too, such as on this very site.

Answer (score 0):

First let me say: That's a good question! The short answer to it is:

> **No**, it is not a good practice to annotate fields such as `user_email` or `username` with `@Id`.

For a deeper look into the *Why*, let us first remember how a primary key (PK) is defined. In most SQL-oriented database systems, the [PK definition](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp) follows at least two assumptions under which a PK always is:

- (i) NOT NULL
- (ii) UNIQUE

The implications with respect to your idea/question:

- (a):

  A `username` or a `user_email` value would have be set to a `User` instance before you could persist it to a database. In the case, it was missing or be known only at a later point in time: Persistence = impossible. Vice versa, it could never be set to an *unknown* value, aka `null`, e.g., if a user simply can not provide his/her email address (even though a rare case in 2018).
- (b):

  Actual values for `username`/`user_email` tend to be unique in most applications. Nevertheless, in the application's business logic you'd have to ensure, no other user inputs an already existent/known `username`/`user_email` twice. If you had `@Id` annotated, again: Persistence = impossible. Still, most likely, allowing duplicates on one of these fields would violate its semantics any way.

If you'd annotate `user_id` as `@Id`field: No pain in both cases.

In an ORM context, [the JPA specification document](https://github.com/javaee/jpa-spec/blob/master/jsr338-MR/JavaPersistence.pdf) expands this definition and states on page 31:

> The value of its primary key **uniquely** identifies an entity instance within a persistence context and to
>   EntityManager operations as described in Chapter 3, “Entity Operations”. The application **must not change** the value of the primary key. The behavior is undefined if this occurs.

This yields the next implication

- (c)

  By definition, you are not allowed to *change* values of `@Id` fields programmatically / at runtime. The control of such fields should remain exclusively on the side of the object-relational mapper implementing the JPA specification.

As pointed out in the answer by *[Bohemian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256196/bohemian)*, a `username` or `user_email` might be subject to change over the lifetime of your application. The reason: Data are fluid from the perspective of an application user. Users might want to change these properties (at some time in the future), e.g if they get married or change their email provider.

Nevertheless, it is generally possible to annotate fields of type `String` (and others), see p. 31:

> A simple primary key or a field or property of a composite primary key should be one of the following types: any `Java primitive type`; any primitive wrapper type; `java.lang.String`;
>   `java.util.Date`; `java.sql.Date`; `java.math.BigDecimal`; `java.math.BigInteger`.

So one might get tempted and say: Well, let's go with that! However, one should step back and reflect what (a) the domain or (b) the intended use cases of the application impose on the intended application's database schema. As discussed above, this is especially important in your scenario.

With these "real world" considerations in mind, you'll be better off to only annotate `@Id` to a surrogate key, such as `user_id` in your example°. This one will not change throughout the lifetime of your database. Question: Why won't it change? Answer: There is no practical reason to satisfy a business case defined by application users.

Hope this helps.

°Hint

*Better use `Long` instead of `Integer` right from the start; you'll thus have enough primary key values way beyond your lifetime as a SW-developer (True for >99.5% of all applications).*